# A Core Data Predicate to check if child Entities contain an attribute or "keypath"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, core-data, nspredicate

I'm constructing a Core Data NSFetchRequest in objective c.  In the data model there is an abstract parent entity (which contains 4 basic attributes), and many different child entities that include attributes that aren't in the parent.  Some children contain attributes that share the same name and data types.

I am applying the fetchRequest to the parent entity, so that it will search all instances of the child entities to see if a "keypath" exists.

Can I construct a predicate that will only return child entities that contain a particular attribute?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.entityAttributes",attribute.name];
```

Here, *attribute* is an instance of NSAttributeDescription, and the goal is to search for other entities that have an attribute of a matching name within their list of attributes, but I'm not sure how to format the predicate.

I can clarify further if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are inspecting the instances instead of the model? You can easily find out which entity types have a given property

```
for (NSEntityDescription* entityDescription in [self managedObjectModel]) {
  if ([[entityDescription propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"someProperty"] != nil) {
    // objects of this entity support the property you're looking for
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to query the instances because the final goal is to get the distinct values of the attribute from all of the instances that have define it.  I'm using a loop similar to the one you listed here in order to procedurally generate the index table for the workaround that Wienke suggested.

Comment: Actually, I think you should go with edsko's suggestion. When the `if` condition in his code is true, you've got the entity description that will scoop up all the instances that have the property you want. You just run a fetch on that entity description, without a predicate, and there you are. The beauty of it is that if you need only instances with particular values for that property, you can add a predicate for them to the fetch. (Thank you both: I wasn't aware you could get so much info straight from the mom.)

Comment: If it's performance you're after, then perhaps you should rethink your database model a little bit. Core Data will store different entities in different database tables, so even if you come up with a complicated query that works across entities it probably won't perform very well. Maybe you're better off adding the property to the parent entity instead and just leave it unused in subentities that don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, worthy of some experiment (in the absence of better help).

I tried this predicate on a managed object:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.attributesByName.allKeys CONTAINS %@", @“nameOfAttrSought”];
```

But I got this error: “unimplemented SQL generation for predicate.”

Which suggests to me that SQL is not prepared to dig into NSArrays, which is what you get by querying the NSEntityDescription for its attribute names.

If nobody else can come up with a predicate that will do what you want through a direct fetch request, I would suggest this workaround:

Define an entity `Namer` that has a single string attr `named` and a to-many relationship `members`. Create one of these for each of the possible attrs that your target child entities can have. 
Then give the child entites a to-many relationship to `Namer` called `namers` (the inverse of the `members` relationship). Upon insertion, add the appropriate “namers” to this relationship.
Then you could make a fetch predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“ANY namers == %@“, namerSought];
// ("namerSought" is an instance of Namer.)
```

Comment: I, too, ran across that error.  It doesn't seem to like when I try to use attributes that aren't defined in the parent entity.  Also, I decided to use an approach almost exactly like what you described here.  It's definitely not the ideal solution, and I hope someone might know a trick we don't, still.  Otherwise I'll mark this answered in a day or so.  Thanks.